# How to force Chef's yum_repository resource to use "makecache fast"?

Tags: chef-infra, yum

I'm using yum_repository to create .repo files in Centos.

Some of my repositories are so huge that caching repos last very very long.

I found that resource yum_repository in Chef is running "yum -q -y makecache" and also I found that running "makecache fast" is extremaly faster and enough in my case.

How can I use edit_resource to override executed command or how would i execute "makecache fast" in other way?

I won't write own resource to swap yum_repository because it may be too hard and expensive to adjust all my existing cookbooks to new resource.